# ReadyAPI-Request an access token in headless mode fails for oauth 2 token retrieval in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: soapui, groovy, readyapi

I am using the below code to generate accessToken.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.actions.oauth.OltuOAuth2ClientFacade;
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.editor.inspectors.auth.TokenType;
    import com.eviware.soapui.model.support.ModelSupport;
    
    // Set up variables
    def project = ModelSupport.getModelItemProject(context.getModelItem());
    def authProfile = project.getAuthRepository().getEntry("user");
    def oldToken = authProfile.getAccessToken();
    def tokenType = TokenType.ACCESS;
    //log.info("OLD TOKEN: " + oldToken);
    
    // Create a facade object
    def oAuthFacade = new OltuOAuth2ClientFacade(tokenType);
    
    // Request an access token in headless mode
    oAuthFacade.requestAccessToken(authProfile, true, true);
    
    // Wait until the access token gets updated
    //while(oldToken == authProfile.getAccessToken()) {
    //}
    //The sleep method can be used instead of a while loop
    //sleep(3000);
    
    for(int i = 0; i<=6000; i++){
    if(oldToken != authProfile.getAccessToken()){
    break
    }
    sleep(1)
    }
    
    // Post the info to the log
    def token = authProfile.getAccessToken();
    log.info("NEW TOKEN: " + authProfile.getAccessToken());
    
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "accessToken", token )
```

This code works without issues in laptop. But when configured in CI/CD pipeline, the code fails with the error message:-

**An error occurred [/tmp/JxBrowser/7.12/libbrowsercore_toolkit.so: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory], see error log for details An error occurred in the script of the Groovy Script test step [Groovy Script 3]: [errorlog] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/JxBrowser/7.12/libbrowsercore_toolkit.so: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/JxBrowser/7.12/libbrowsercore_toolkit.so: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a package missing which is required to run Chromium or JX Browser in order to execute your script successfully.

The missing library is **libX11.so.6**.

You can install this in Debian system with this command,

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-6 -y
```

You can also look up other necessary package names by typing the below line in your terminal and then hitting the tab key a couple of times.

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-
```

Check the listed packages and then install the once you require.

You can also use this command to install few other packages that might be required,

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Then try to execute your code.

For other OS types, you can find the required packages name [here](https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/Diag/MissingLibX11).